# How to combine where and first in go range

Tags: go, hugo

I am new to Go and Hugo site generator and currently creating a simple theme. I am trying to combine a `where` filter along with `first` function and I am not able to make it work.

What I want is to get first 10 items in the `post` section

```
{{ range where .Data.Pages "Section" "post" }}
    <li><a href="{{.RelPermalink}}">{{.Title}}</a> <em>{{.Summary}}</em></li>
{{ end }}
```

The above works fine, but how do I make it return only the first 10 items (the below does not work):

```
{{ range first 10 where .Data.Pages "Section" "post" }}
    <li><a href="{{.RelPermalink}}">{{.Title}}</a> <em>{{.Summary}}</em></li>
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example from the [Hugo Template Functions documentation](https://www.gohugo.io/templates/functions/) that I think means you're just missing parentheses:

```
{{ range first 5 (where .Data.Pages "Section" "post") }}
   {{ .Content }}
{{ end }}
```